# How to watch dynamically latitude and longitude in geofence

Tags: cordova, ionic2, android-geofence, ionic3, ionic-native

I have application when I have done the geofence I am able to get the notification perfectly.

What my goal is to get the notification dynamically when ever I reach the radius.

now when I add geofence addorupdate function works fine only once if I need to get again another notification then I want to add again.

instead of that is there any way where I can watch my latitude and longitude background without adding again and again.

here is my code

```
  lat 
  long

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private geofence: Geofence, private geolocation: Geolocation) {

    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
    // resp.coords.latitude
    // resp.coords.longitude
    console.log(resp);
    console.log("invoking the geolocation success");
    this.lat = resp.coords.latitude;
    this.long = resp.coords.longitude;

    console.log(this.lat);
    console.log(this.long);

    this.addGeofence();
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error getting location', error);
    });
    console.log(this.lat);
    console.log(this.long);
    // initialize the plugin
    geofence.initialize().then(
      // resolved promise does not return a value
      (success) => {
        console.log(success);
        console.log('Geofence Plugin Ready')
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(err)
      })
  }

  private addGeofence() {
    //options describing geofence
    let fence = {
      id: '69ca1b88-6fbe-4e80-a4d4-ff4d3748acdb', //any unique ID
      latitude:       this.lat, //center of geofence radius
      longitude:      this.long,
      radius:         50, //radius to edge of geofence in meters
      transitionType: 3, //see 'Transition Types' below
      notification: { //notification settings
          id:             1, //any unique ID
          title:          'You crossed bangalore', //notification title
          text:           'You just arrived to bangalore.', //notification body
          openAppOnClick: true //open app when notification is tapped
      }
    }
    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
    // resp.coords.latitude
    // resp.coords.longitude
    this.lat = resp.coords.latitude;
    this.long = resp.coords.longitude;

    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error getting location', error);
    });
    console.log(fence);

    this.geofence.addOrUpdate(fence).then(
      (success) => {
        console.log(success);
        console.log('Geofence added')
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log(err);
        console.log('Geofence failed to add')
      }); 
  }
```

how can I get the notification dynamically everytime once we add the geofence?

Comment: Here's a solution in geolocation. https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ionic2/5840/geolocation/22110/watching-the-position#t=201705291412218335685

Comment: There is also geofence.onTransitionReceived that I am not sure about whether it gives back on each movement or just when you enter a point